# telerik assembly web page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

Getting an error when we try to deploy our web application, in bin folder is dll :
Telerik.Web.UI.dll
and
Telerik.Web.UI.Skins

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
Line 2:
Line 3:  <%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
Line 4:
Line 5:

Source File: /telerik/default.aspx    Line: 3

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: do what the comment at the bottom suggest and you will find which assembly is missing. The easiest way is you install the telerik libraries on the Server.

Comment: @slfan: after adding this to my regedit-> Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Telerik.Web.UI
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Telerik.Web.UI | Domain ID: 4
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
Calling assembly : (Unknown).